# openssl_private_encrypt() returns false with output of 0

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I am trying to use the PHP function openssl_private_encrypt() to encrypt an uploaded file prior to saving it (see code snippet below), however it's bool is returning false and the encrypted content return is returning nothing. No errors are being displayed or reported.

```
        $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);

        openssl_private_encrypt($data,$encrypted,$key);

        $hash = sha1($encrypted);
        file_put_contents('/path/to/folder/'.$hash,$encrypted);
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: how did you initialize $key ? check if it is correct resorurce (var_dump($key))

Comment: $key is pulled as file_get_contents('key.pem');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about PHP but in C/C++(OpenSSL) asymmetric encryption(RSA mainly) works on data with length less than the key size. And normally it is used to encrypt hash values. If you want to encrypt large(more the ~256 bytes)amount of data you'd better use some symmetric(block) cipher like AES or TriDES. Symmetric ciphers are much faster by the way.

PS Sorry I don't have enough reputation to put this post into comments.

Comment: It's beyond me why they don't just say so in a meaningful error messsage. How are we supposed to know this? Thanks for the explanation, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You should proper initialize private key (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php)

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private ('file://path/to/file.pem');
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);

openssl_private_encrypt($data,$encrypted,$key);

$hash = sha1($encrypted);
file_put_contents('/path/to/folder/'.$hash,$encrypted);
```