# Encrypt binary files with openssl_private_encrypt in php

Tags: php, encryption, digital-signature, php-openssl

I want to encrypt with private key using Symfony framework. It works with non-binary files but not with binary files.

```
$gestor = fopen($file, "rb");
$data = fread($gestor, filesize($file));
fclose($gestor);


$fp=fopen("cert.key","r");
$priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);

$res = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

$crypttext="";
$response = openssl_private_encrypt($data,$crypttext,$res);
//$response is false and $crypttext is empty

$sign_file = fopen($tsrfile.".sign", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($sign_file, $crypttext);
fclose($sign_file);
```

Comment: How big are the files? What is the error that you see?

Comment: I can decrypt with public key, with text file there aren't problems. The binary file  has 1.2kb

Comment: see 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501902/openssl-private-encrypt-returns-false-with-output-of-0