# Encrypt large inputs in PHP using OpenSSL and a password-protected SSH key?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I have a CLI tool that writes encrypted data to the local filesystem that is never transmitted over the network.

I am able to encrypt the data using a password-protected SSH key, but since the generated key is assymetric (RSA), it can only encrypt/decrypt data that is shorter than the key, which is not ideal for my use case:

I generate the SSH key:

```php
$config = [
    "private_key_bits"   => 4096,
    "private_key_type"   => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    "encrypt_key"        => true,
    "encrypt_key_cipher" => OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC
];

openssl_pkey_export( openssl_pkey_new( $config ), $privateKeyOut, $password );

if ( ! file_put_contents( $_SERVER['HOME'] . '/.ssh/fookey.pem', $privateKeyOut ) ) {
    throw new \RuntimeException( 'Could not write private key.' );
}
```

Then I encrypt/decrypt as follows:

```php
public function encrypt( string $plain_text ): string {
    $key = openssl_pkey_get_private( file_get_contents( $_SERVER['HOME'] . '/.ssh/fookey.pem' ), App::getVar( 'enc_password' ) );

    $success = openssl_private_encrypt( $plain_text, $cipher_text, $key );

    if ( ! $success ) {
        throw new \RuntimeException( 'Encrypt failed.' );
    }

    return base64_encode( $cipher_text );
}

public function decrypt( string $cipher_text ): string {
    $key = openssl_pkey_get_private( file_get_contents( $_SERVER['HOME'] . '/.ssh/fookey.pem' ), App::getVar( 'enc_password' ) );

    $success = openssl_private_decrypt( base64_decode( $cipher_text ), $plain_text, $key );

    if ( ! $success ) {
        throw new \RuntimeException( 'Decrypt failed.' );
    }

    return $plain_text;
}
```

*PS: The value of `App::getVar( 'enc_password' )` is provided by the user through an interactive input when he runs the script.*

Is it possible to tweak this script to use a Symmetric encryption key instead, that can encrypt/decrypt large inputs?

Comment: ___it can only encrypt/decrypt data that is shorter than the key___ Please would you explain what you mean by that, because it does not sound right

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not an expert in encryption. This assumption comes from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19513142/2056484

Comment: @RiggsFolly: RSA can only encrypt/decrypt data whose length is less than the length of the modulus. If proper padding is used, and it should be, then the plaintext must be even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I eventually figured it out. Thanks to @TimWolla for pointing me in the right direction.

I'm using [laminas/crypt](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-crypt) package (successor of [zend/crypt](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt)). It has support for [hybrid RSA encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31563/when-why-is-rsa-hybrid-encryption-used-rather-than-alternatives):

To encrypt:

- Generates a random symmetric key with something like `random_bytes(32)`
- Encrypts the big data **using the symmetric key**
- Encrypts the symmetric key **using RSA**

To decrypt:

- Decrypts the symmetric key using RSA (the RSA key can be password protected)
- Decrypts the big data using the symmetric key, which has no limitation on the size it can decrypt.

This works because RSA can't encrypt long data, but we can use a random string to encrypt the big data and encrypt the random string instead.

As per laminas/crypt [Hybrid](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-crypt/blob/3.10.x/docs/book/hybrid.md) example:

```php
use Laminas\Crypt\Hybrid;
use Laminas\Crypt\PublicKey\RsaOptions;

// Generate public and private key
$rsaOptions = new RsaOptions([
    'pass_phrase' => 'test'
]);

$rsaOptions->generateKeys([
    'private_key_bits' => 4096
]);

// Get keys as strings. This can be saved to file, etc.
$publicKey  = $rsaOptions->getPublicKey()->toString();
$privateKey = $rsaOptions->getPrivateKey()->toString();

// Encrypt / Decrypt.
$hybrid     = new Hybrid();
$ciphertext = $hybrid->encrypt('message', $publicKey);
$plaintext  = $hybrid->decrypt($ciphertext, $privateKey, 'test'); // pass-phrase

printf($plaintext === 'message' ? "Success\n" : "Error\n");
```

Comment: *Encrypts the big data using the symmetric key*  Be careful with the AES scheme you use.  [AES-ECB isn't all that secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption)